# Best way to draw a pixel in Xamarin.Forms ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, drawing, xamarin.forms, signature, skiasharp

I know SkiaSharp exists, but it is not supported in Xamarin.Forms.
Can I simply draw using 1x1 BoxViews? But I think drawing a signature (with touchevent) may impact performance. Is there any better option?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I Need to capture a user signature. I know, there is signaturepad component and i use it in xamarin forms, but in uwp is not supported, and i Need it to implement in this platform too

Comment: it's open source, why don't you extend it to work with UWP?

Comment: It's my plan, but now deadline of my project force me to find a faster solution

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a signature, you can try to use https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad and create a custom Control that is using it. Or you can have a look at https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms that is basically a translation of the first one for Xamarin.Forms. Unfortunately it is outdated, but you could use it as a guideline for your own implementation.